# Layout com cores diferentes nos TextBox (Safari e Chrome)

Tags: jquery, css, razor

O Safari está esmaecendo as cores dentro que não são @Html.ComboboxFor, como faço para não esmanescer nos textbox?

Estou usando CSS e JQuery, Segue a foto

Select não esmanesce no Safari:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CEP.IdCidade, (SelectList)ViewBag.Cidades, "Selecione", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "IdCidade", @style = "line-height: 2" })
```

Text esmanesce no Safari:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Bairro.DescBairro, new { @class = "form-control tam-50", @id = "DescBairro" })
```

Segue uma print da Comparação com o Chrome:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se vc não tem nenhuma classe css que está fazendo isso, abre um chamado no Bootstrap, pois é interno. [GitHub Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues)

Comment: Vou fazer assim:
input[type="text"]:disabled {
    color: #000000
} 
Porém não sei a cor automática, estou procurando...

Comment: Acho que o esmaecer é por conta do `disabled`, tenta adicionar um `color:#000 !important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte no CSS:

```
input[type="text"]:disabled {
    color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 1);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 1);
} 

select[disabled='disabled'] {
    color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 1);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 1);
}
```